# dotnet command not working on centos server, runtime installed

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, installation, centos7

I installed aspnet core runtime (aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.3) on a centOS 7 server. 
following this guide from microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/runtime?pivots=os-linux#download-and-manually-install

my server doesn't have internet connection.

After installation, when I run any command, e.g. 
`dotnet --info`
it says it can't find any installed dotnet sdk:

```
$ dotnet --info
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.3
  Commit:  4a9f85e9f8

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.3 [/home/myuser/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.3 [/home/myuser/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Previously, I downloaded the rpm package and installed it with `rpm -ivh` command, same result

What can I do to fix this?
Note that I don't have **internet access** in the server

EDIT: The problem: I don't need SDK to run this command or any command I am using.

Anyways I've tried installing SDK, it says it can't find any compatible frameworks

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? you just installed runtime, and the error says there is no sdk.

Comment: The problem is I don't need the sdk to run this command, or any other command I am using, why would it ask about the sdk ?

Answer (score 0):

You installed the .net runtime but didn't install the any sdk. for you to be able use asp.net core you need to install both. you can visit asp.net core documentation for the difference between them. but you can just visit https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download to download the appropriate sdk you need.

[image: this is what you see when you go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download]
[image: form there click on Linux (as is the case with you) and the advanced]
[image: choose asp.net 3.1]
[image: make sure you download both the sdk and runtime]

nb: I assume you are doing this from a gui. i'm sure there are commands for installing the asp.net core runtime and SDK from command prompt. but what is important is that YOU ARE MISSING THE SDK!!

Comment: Thanks. but why do I need the SDK ? I've deployed using asp.net core runtime only before in other servers. anyways I made a fresh install.